# одновременная передача данных

Tags: php

Согласно документации одной из бирж криптовалют для создания ордера я использую такой код

```
    getAuth(order_create, Array(
    "pair"=>"$value[pair]",
    "quantity"=>"$value[quantity]",
    "price"=>"$value[price]",
    "type"=>"$value[type]"
```

Написанный мной интерфейс подключения к бирже позволяет с помощью  form отправлять данные по API на создание нескольких ордеров одновременно нажатием на одну кнопку. Перебирая с помощью foreach массив $_POST я могу сформировать несколько массивов под создание нескольких ордеров:

```
foreach ($data as $k => $value){
    if ($value[chek] == "on") {
        $orcr = getAuth(order_create, Array(
        "pair"=>"$value[pair]",
        "quantity"=>"$value[quantity]",
        "price"=>"$value[price]",
        "type"=>"$value[type]"
  ));

    }
}
```

Но я не знаю как дать их бирже одновременно.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то одновременно передать массив? Есть идея писать ордера в базу, сверять есть ли в списке ордеров на бирже эти ордера, если нет, то создать ордера, но это совсем крайний случай. Хотелось бы в идеале их создать одновременно, одним нажатием кнопки. Если нет, то создать некую очередь, из которой бы они автоматически создались бы на бирже. Спасибо!

Comment: Если API биржи не имеет возможности отправки нескольких ордеров, то одновременно у вас это сделать не получится. Очередь вам также не позволит это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, формируй массивы. Если такое поддерживает API биржи, просто отправляй через POST данные, с нужными заголовками. Скорее всего в каждом массиве на определенный ордер, тебе нужно указать доп. поле(индекс), который будет соответствовать "idшнику" определенного ордера, прочитай в документации, возможно там сказано, как найти такой id!